# Line continuation character in Scala

Tags: scala, newline

I want to split the following Scala code line like this:

```
ConditionParser.parseSingleCondition("field=*value1*").description 
  must equalTo("field should contain value1")
```

But which is the line continuation character?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Wrap it in parentheses:

```
(ConditionParser.parseSingleCondition("field=*value1*").description 
  must equalTo("field should contain value1"))
```

Scala does not have a "line continuation character" - it infers a semicolon always when:

- An expression can end
- The following (not whitespace) line begins not with a token that can start a statement
- There are no unclosed `(` or `[` found before

Thus, to "delay" semicolon inference one can place a method call or the dot at the end of the line or place the dot at the beginning of the following line:

```
ConditionParser.
parseSingleCondition("field=*value1*").
description must equalTo("field should contain value1")

a +
b +
c

List(1,2,3)
  .map(_+1)
```

Comment: I've seen notation common in javascript, when you move a dot to the start of the next line

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Yes, start of line is common but not at the end of line (the former does only work for Scala when the expression is wrapped in parentheses).

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Huh, I was not aware that we are allowed to place the dot at the beginning of the following line. Thanks for the hint! I edited my answer to mention this.

Comment: The dot placement should be at the end in Scala scripts executed using `-i` option.

Comment: So when can "wrapping in parenthesis" be used? is it part of the core syntax?