# How can I force the semicolon in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala.

Is it possible to force using a semicolon as the end of a line ?

e.g.

```
 val s = "my line"
         + " ends here";
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335388/line-continuation-character-in-scala

Comment: @som-snytt This here also looked somewhat duplicate-ish: (Scala semicolon inference example)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778992/scala-semicolon-inference-example]. But then again, it didn't fully answer the question, so... I don't know.

Comment: Propose to change the title to "How can I prevent semicolon inference in Scala", that would look much more like a canonical question then. "Line continuation" and "forcing semicolons" is just not what you usually want. Something with "avoid semicolon inference" would be much easier to google.

Comment: I do want to force using a semicolon as the end of a line (I like the style of putting the + at the start of the next line instead of at the end of the first line).

Comment: I've rolled back Gabriele Petronella's edit for now. That's exactly the reason why I proposed the title change in the comment instead of editing.

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin Thanks for the advice. I think I found the answer somehow that it's not the scala style of putting `+` at the start of the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to "force using a semicolon", quite the contrary: you want to avoid that a semicolon is inferred at the end of the first line.

Several possibilities here:

1. Move plus to previous line (that's the preferred way to do it):

   ```
   val s = "my line" +
           "ends here";
   ```
2. Explicit method calls starting with `.` prevent the semicolon from being inferred (this works reasonably well for "builder-pattern" like chains of methods, but looks ugly for `+`):

   ```
   val s = "my line"
         .+("ends here");
   ```
3. Add parentheses. Semicolons are never inferred inside parentheses:

   ```
   val s = ("my line"
           + "ends here");
   ```

Comment: Thanks. But I do want to force using a semicolon as the end of a line (I like the style of putting the `+` at the start of the next line).

Comment: @AlphaTAN Well, Scala is open-source, it theoretically could be possible to modify the first few stages of the compiler accordingly. Unfortunately, I can't give you any advice on maintaining your own fork of the compiler, maybe the people from Twitter could say more on that. Twitter is the only organization that I'm aware of that actually forked the compiler and used it for something non-trivial / non-experimental.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I found the answer somehow that it's not the scala style of putting `+` at the start of the next line.

Comment: @AlphaTAN Sorry, I can't quite follow? Do you still want to modify the behavior of semicolons, or have you decided to just follow the Scala conventions instead (it's certainly easier than trying to modify every new language that you learn -- that's for sure). Should I revert the title to the canonical question again?

Comment: The title of the question is good, no need to revert it again. I do want to find a way of forcing the usage of semicolon at the beginning. Then I followed the links of the comments and read your answer, I found that I'd better to follow the scala style. Thanks.